# Why aren't my Postgres WAL segments (up to the point of turning on archiving) being archived?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.2

The `pg_xlog` directory for my master cluster looks like this:

```
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  16M Jun 21 21:42 000000010000000000000001
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  16M Jun 21 22:42 000000010000000000000002
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  16M Jun 21 23:42 000000010000000000000003
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  16M Jun 22 00:42 000000010000000000000004
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  16M Jun 22 01:42 000000010000000000000005
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  16M Jun 22 01:49 000000010000000000000006
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  16M Jun 22 01:55 000000010000000000000007
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  16M Jun 22 02:05 000000010000000000000008
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  16M Jun 22 02:30 000000010000000000000009
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  16M Jun 22 02:50 00000001000000000000000A
```

The `pg_xlog/archive_status` directory looks like this:

```
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 0 Jun 22 01:49 000000010000000000000006.done
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 0 Jun 22 01:55 000000010000000000000007.done
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 0 Jun 22 02:05 000000010000000000000008.done
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 0 Jun 22 02:30 000000010000000000000009.done
```

When I first turned on archiving `006` was the current segment, but why weren't `001`-`005` archived anyway? Last time I set up archiving on an existing cluster (which was yesterday - I've been experimenting), **all** log segments were archived when I turned archiving on, despite the `pg_xlog` directory containing more than 50 previous log segments.

Relevant settings:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
archive_mode = on
wal_keep_segments = 2048  # I know, right :)
archive_timeout = 3600
archive_command = 'rsync -aq --delay-updates --ignore-existing %p postgres@db-slave:/mnt/pgsql/'
```

Note: I did change all of these settings (including `was_level`, which was `minimal` previously) when I turned on archiving earlier. Could it be that my wal level wasn't sufficient to warrant archiving, or because there is a mismatch between the prior level and the current level?

Comment: These are all good questions. I don't have answers for you off the top of my head; I'd need to go digging in the sources and do more testing than I presently have time for for a dba.SE answer. If you don't get any response here, you should try posting on pgsql-general and *make sure to link back to this post*.

Comment: @Craig - thanks, good idea. I just mailed the issue to pgsql- general.

Comment: Last time did you stopped/restarted PostgreSQL with immediate shutdown? This would explain why it archived, as it applied the xlogs on startup (with archiving enabled).

Comment: I did a hard restart on the master, but the slave hasn't ever been started.

Comment: @MatheusOl - Sorry, I forgot to @ your name on my previous reply.

Comment: @orokusaki - you forgot and I didn't see, =P... But what "hard" restart mean? If it isn't a fast stop (as used by /etc/init.d scripts) then it would explain everything...

Comment: @MatheusOl It was a `pg_ctlcluster 9.2 mycluster stop --force`, which resulted in an "immediate" shutdown because it ended up taking too long to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to the fact that at least the 5th WAL segment was used for recovery to get the database into a consistent state after an `immediate` stop. I'm not sure why the WAL segments wouldn't still be useful (e.g., for point in time recovery).